# Maintaining materialized views without writing 100s of upserts ...should i use another timeseries or streaming technology?

Tags: postgresql, time-series, streaming, influxdb, materialized-views

I'm a little stuck. I am bulding software around IoT devices and now I want to maintain loads of up-to-date materialized views for dashboarding. I am getting in the order of 1M events per day and want maintain A LOT of pre-computed, durable and accurate aggregates on the data.

e.g. if I have a IoT device making sales, I want to maintain sales-by-device materialized view
`(date, deviceId, sales_sum)`

Quite simple.

Now I might also want to store other bits of information by date, `deviceId`

`(date, deviceId, sales_sum, sales_count, refund_sum, refund_count, service_count, err_count)`

The aggregates to maintain are quite simple (just sums/counts). I can do this myself within from my calling application (JavaScript) using upserts through a database driver/ORM query builder or raw SQL, but that
i) suffers from duplicate data issues (if my application loses connection to the database after sending an upsert commands it may resend the same data leading to double counting)
ii) is tedious to write these upserts. not well supported in query builders (I have to drop in raw SQL code).

A solution to (i) is also inserting transitionally into another table an unique_id that represents the update, but that is tedious (ii) and I suddenly feel like I'm rolling my own solution to a solved problem.

I see databases like influxdb. I am looking at it, but the downsides are
i) i will now be storing data in 2 places - my existing postgresdb and then my aggregates in influxdb. Honestly I think that is fine... I will have to recombine them in my application code (or maybe I can use something like GraphQL to do it for me)
ii) it seems like influxdb wants to keep my RAW timeseries data. I am happy to hand off data to it in a format like (date, deviceId, **sale-to-sum-onto-existing-sale-sum-field**). You don't need to keep my raw time series data lying around.
iii) seems it's not that real time? looking at the tasks, seems like it updates the materialize views from the raw time series, rather than when the time series comes in
iv) not sure of the cost if I want to maintain loads of different views with long retention

I am still considering influxdb, but i don't need it to keep my raw timeseries, just my aggregates. I feel like I'm doing something that must have been done 1000s of times before.

I would be interested in timescaleDB, but I'm on AWS RDS and that extension is not available as per the license.

After some advice and opinions. I don't want to be making 10s-100s of custom upsert queries (even with ORM query builders) and figuring out how I

Thanks

Comment: 1. Why don't you know if your insert worked? 2. What do you have against SQL - are you writing your javascript with a front-end-builder?

Comment: Byzantine generals problem
1. Your app tells the database to upsert some data.
2. The database does it and sends a message tell your app code it did it.
3. But that connection is severed/power outage before application receives confirmation.
4. Once connection or power is restored, app doesn't know if the SQL command was successful. 
5. Application tries again
6. Now you have sent the SQL command twice and double counted/summed

Comment: I personally use knex. I've tried sequelize before and hated it. knex is OK (I write in typescript). but i stil have to drop into raw SQL to be able to do multi-row upserts.

Comment: 'are you writing your javascript with a front-end-builder' <--- not sure what you meant by that?

Comment: If you are genuinely trying to solve the byzantine generals problem without your data having any sort of identity or uniqueness (which your upserts seem to imply) then I'm not aware of anything simple that can solve that. If you have `(today, 'dev01', 1.23)` and then separately `(today, 'dev01', 1.23)` and need to reliably have those both added to the database exactly once in the presence of the failure of any combination of client, server, network at any time I *think* (and it's not my speciality) that you need to accept arbitrary delay (which sounds unacceptable to your case).

Answer (score 1):

There is only one correct way to maintain redundant information like a table of aggregates: a database trigger. That will automatically maintain your “materialized views”, and your application does not have to take care of that. Moreover, since the trigger automatically runs in the same transaction as the data modifying statement, you are guaranteed to stay consistent.

Comment: oooh, there only one *correct* way? where did you learn that? is the materialized view smart enough to only do differential updates? does it scale well? I'm going to want to add 10s of materiailzed views, some of them across multiple tables. can easily get 10s of inserts during peak time into our tables

Comment: There is no incremental materialized view maintenance in PostgreSQL, which is why I suggested a hand-rolled implementation using triggers. And yes, that will be a severe performance hit for all data modifications. See it like that: you can either have fast queries with a solution like the one I suggest, which will make data modifications very slow. Or you can have it the other way around. You can only optimize one at the expense of the other.